# REACT: access parent ref in nested children generated by recursion

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a nested list / file tree like component. I can expand first parents height, but cannot expand again when expanding nested child's list.

How can I access parents ref from a nested child generated by recursion to transition parents height to show nested child's list as well?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.